# JSON get child value by javascript

Tags: javascript

```
IN.API.Raw("/company-search:(companies:(name,id))?keywords=National Palace Museum&count=1").method('GET').result(function(value) {
var Objcompany = JSON.stringify(value);
console.log(Objcompany);
})
```

it shows {"companies":{"_total":1,"values":[{"id":527345,"name":"National Palace Museum"}]}}

so i tried

```
console.log(Objcompany.companies.values[0].id);
```

but it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined "

whats error ??

Comment: console.log(Objcompany.companies.values[0].id);

Comment: could you add the implementation of this code, because this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well as for me:

```js
var Objcompany = {"companies":{"_total":1,"values":[{"id":527345,"name":"National Palace Museum"}]}}

console.log( Objcompany.companies.values[0].id )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
console.log(Objcompany["companies"]["values"][0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Objcompany.companies.values[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4xttdc5/); But your code was correct. IDK why the browser's telling you that.

```
var Objcompany = {"companies":{"_total":1,"values":[{"id":527345,"name":"National Palace Museum"}]}}

console.log(Objcompany.companies.values[0].id);
```

Comment: So you don't know ? and you 're answering ^^

Comment: @Hacketo I don't know why the browser is throwing that error since, uppon trying his very own code on my machine it gives no such error.

Either the error is caused by another variable somewhere else in the code or something really weird is going on.